# How do I add an account via outlook COM?

Tags: c#, com, outlook

I have gone through tons of examples for using the Outlook COM library to access Outlook programmatically. For context, my scenario is the following:

I need to see how many emails are in another user's inbox. I have that users email address and password. This is because we share a department mailbox that I need to monitor.

I have tried variations of the following:

```
Outlook.Application app = new Outlook.Application();
Outlook.NameSpace ns = app.GetNamespace("MAPI");
Recipient oRep = ns.CreateRecipient("notMe@notMe.com");
ns.Logon("notMe@notMe.com", "password", false, true);
MAPIFolder inbox = ns.GetSharedDefaultFolder(oRep, OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox);
var foo = inbox.Items.Count;
```

This ONLY works if I have configured the current computers outlook by adding the other account. I want this to be able to work on ANY computer with outlook, regardless of if "notMe" has been added to outlook before. I have seen suggestions like:

Logoff and exit the app, then re-open it before trying to access the other account

Access the folders like ns.Folders["notMe@notMe.com"];

Nothing has worked so far. I appreciate any help.

Comment: GetSharedDefaultFolder is the way to go. Do you get an error when you call it? Were you given the right to access that mailbox\folder?

Comment: I don't get an error, I get MY Inbox, not that of the other user. I DO get the inbox of the other user if I set outlook up ahead of time for two accounts, but I don't want to do that.

Comment: So no matter what recipient you pass to CreateRecipient, you end up with your own mailbox?

Comment: I was mistaken. I don't get my inbox. I DO get what I assume is the other inbox, but if I call any methods I get an exception. The last line in this example throws a System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException : {"The operation failed."}. I have verified that the email and password are correct.

Comment: What email and password? When you call Logon? Logon takes the name of an existing profile, not an SMTP address. The password parameter is not used. What happen if you open that folder from Outlook (File | Open | Other user's Folder)?